# Sorting of Arrays in Object with recursive search

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I am trying to sort every Array by Name in an JSON-Object using Node.js.
I manage to sort just the Array with Underscore.js, but how can I input the whole Object and just get the Object back finished sorted?

Thinking about looking through the object recursively for Arrays and sort every one of them, but how can I do that?

Here is an example Object with just sorting the Array:

```
    var _ = require("./underscore.js")
    var jsonObject = {  "Configuration":{  
          "$":{  
             "xmlns":"http://www.example.com/"
          },
          "ApplicationInstance":{  
             "Description":"Description text here.",
             "Name":"Server1",
             "Class":"System",
             "Visibility":"System",
             "CustomerCreated":"0",
             "Active":"0",
             "IntroducedIn":{  
                "$":{  
                   "xsi:nil":"true",
                   "xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                }
             },
             "Property":[  
                {  
                   "Description":"JMS publisher destination type.",
                   "Name":"jmsJBossPublisher.destinationType",
                   "Class":"System",
                   "Visibility":"System",
                   "LanguageIndependantDescriptionKey":"ActivityGateway-JMSSenderConfiguration.jmsJBossPublisher.destinationType.DESCKEY",
                   "LanguageIndependantNameKey":"ActivityGateway-JMSSenderConfiguration.jmsJBossPublisher.destinationType.NAMEKEY",
                   "CustomerCreated":"1",
                   "Active":"0",
                   "IntroducedIn":"1.1",
                   "AttributeValue":"QUEUE",
                   "AttributeDataTypeName":"String"
                },
                {  
                   "Description":"jmsConnectionFactory properties.",
                   "Name":"jmsConnectionFactory.jndiNameForJmsConnectionFactory",
                   "SecurityClass":"System",
                   "Visibility":"System",
                   "LanguageIndependantDescriptionKey":"ActivityGateway-JMSSenderConfiguration.jmsConnectionFactory.jndiNameForJmsConnectionFactory.DESCKEY",
                   "LanguageIndependantNameKey":"ActivityGateway-JMSSenderConfiguration.jmsConnectionFactory.jndiNameForJmsConnectionFactory.NAMEKEY",
                   "CustomerCreated":"1",
                   "Active":"0",
                   "IntroducedIn":"1.1",
                   "AttributeValue":"ConnectionFactory",
                   "AttributeDataTypeName":"String"
                }
             ],
             "ServerId":"1",
             "ApplicationName":"ActivityGateway",
             "InstanceID":"1"
          }
       }
    };
    console.log(_.sortBy(jsonObject.Configuration.ApplicationInstance.Property,'Name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.sortBy` returns a cloned array, so you'll need to override the previous value.
Try adding this line:

```
jsonObject.Configuration.ApplicationInstance.Property = _.sortBy(jsonObject.Configuration.ApplicationInstance.Property,'Name')
```

Comment: This works. Now how can I do this recursively on all several Arrays in the Object?

Comment: You'll either need to do it manually for each one, or walk the json tree looking for arrays (very inefficient). I suggest you do it manually.

Comment: I have over 700 files with several Arrays and have to do this 2-3times a year, so the manual way will take a lot of time.

Comment: oh ok. do you know recursion in programming?